# Keycloak production setup blank screen issue

Tags: java, postgresql, keycloak

I am trying to setup keycloak, I downloaded the keycloak from this URL: https://www.keycloak.org/downloads (Distribution powered by Quarkus). It runs fine when I run it on dev mode with following command:

> ./kc.sh start-dev

but when I try to run in production mode with postgres database it shows blank page after I register admin and try to login from following URL: http://localhost:8080/admin/master/console/

There are no specific errors on terminal:
[image: Terminal screenshot of keycloak run in debug mode]

Command I used to run keycloak:

> ./kc.sh build --db postgres

> ./kc.sh start --db-url-host localhost --db-username postgres --db-password pass --hostname=localhost --https-key-store-password=secret --http-enabled=true --http-host=localhost --log-level=debug

Followed tutorial: http://www.mastertheboss.com/keycloak/getting-started-with-keycloak-powered-by-quarkus/

**EDIT:
Found the solution as follows:**

> ./kc.sh start --db-url-host localhost --db-username postgres --db-password pass --hostname=localhost --https-key-store-password=secret --http-enabled=true --hostname-strict-https=false --http-host=localhost --log-level=debug

Comment: long time! did you find a solution?

Comment: yes, seems like need to disable https checking for localhost